# Find how many keys have the same value in a hashtable?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

In a hashtable(Java), How can I find how many keys have the same value?

lets says I have:

```
Hashtable<String, int> table = new Hashtable<String, int>();
table.put("a", 1);
table.put("b", 2);
table.put("c", 2);
table.put("d", 2);
```

in this case the keys: b, c, & d would have the same value. how can I detect that?

Comment: You need to build a reverse map, one with with the values as the key and a counter as the value. Then iterate over the first map's entries fetch the entry from the second map whose key matches the first map entry's value, and increment the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to use reference types (objects) in `Hashtable` definition. You cannot use a primitive type like `int`, you have to use `Integer`.

As far as your problem, you could use a small function like this to count how many times a certain value is in the `HashTable`:

```
int countOccurences(Hashtable<String, Integer> table, int value) {
    int count = 0;
    for(String key : table.keySet()) {
        if(table.get(key) == value) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

So if you want to know how many times the value 2 occurs in the table:

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> table = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
table.put("a", 1);
table.put("b", 2);
table.put("c", 2);
table.put("d", 2);
System.out.println(countOccurences(table, 2));
```

This would print 3

Comment: thanks for the simple answer. Im really new to hashtables and maps and all related to it and didnt really understand the first answer.

Comment: you are very welcome :). Just keep practicing, the more you do it the more it will all make sense

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> occurenceForValue = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Hashtable<String, Integer> table = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
Iterator it = table.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if(!occurenceForValue.containsKey(pairs.getValue())
    {
        occurenceForValue.put(pairs.getValue(), 1);
    }
    else
    {
        occurenceForValue.put(pairs.getValue(), occurenceForValue.get(pairs.getValue()) + 1);
    }


    it.remove(); 
}
```

Then occurenceForValue will contains, for each value (as key), the number of occurences.

Edit : Note in my code that I corrected your HashTable definition which used int as generic type which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a primitive type in a Collection (you need to use the wrapper type). I would recommend you use the diamond operator as well. I would get the `keySet` and iterate the keys, get each value and add it to a `SortedSet` (iff the `Set` didn't contain it already, if it did I would print it). So, I believe you are looking for something like this,

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> table = new Hashtable<>();
table.put("a", 1);
table.put("b", 2);
table.put("c", 2);
table.put("d", 2);
Set<String> keySet = table.keySet();
SortedSet<Integer> toCount = new TreeSet<>();
for (String key : keySet) {
    Integer val = table.get(key);
    if (!toCount.contains(val)) {
        System.out.printf("Key %s has value %d%n", key, val);
        toCount.add(val);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Key %s also has value %d%n", key, val);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
Key b has value 2
Key a has value 1
Key d also has value 2
Key c also has value 2
```